# How to center the columns?

Tags: tables

How can we do that columns are not centered? For example; Half term I is at the top of the cell. I want to brindg down center of the cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{longtable}

    \begin{table}
        \begin{center}\label{tab:plan}
            \begin{scriptsize}
                \begin{longtable}{|p{2.8cm}|p{3.9cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{1.8cm}|}
                    \hline
                    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Timeline and Milestones}}
                    \\
                    \hline
                    \centering \textbf{Specific Objectives} & \centering
                    \textbf{Tasks} & \centering \textbf{Schedule} &
                    \textbf{Milestones}
                    \\
                    \hline  \centering \textbf{1.Literature review and preliminary and background
                        work} &
                    \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
                        \item [a)] Literature review of theory and applications,
                        \item [b)] Analysing existing the problems,
                        \item [c)] Familiarizing with the various programs
                    \end{itemize}&\centering Half Term I & Prepare summary literature survey by end of term
                \\
                    \hline
                      \end{longtable}
            \end{scriptsize}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you insist on vertically centered contents, use `m` type columns instead of `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your table i will write like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usepackage{graphics} loaded by beamer
%\usepackage{longtable} in presentation hasn't any sense
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
%\label{tab:plan}% has sense if table has numered caption
    \scriptsize
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{4ex}
%       \begin{center}
%            \begin{scriptsize}
%                \begin{longtable}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}
>{\bfseries}L{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
            L{\dimexpr0.35\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
            L{\dimexpr0.20\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
            L{\dimexpr0.20\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
                            @{}}
    \toprule%\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Timeline and Milestones}}    \\
    \midrule%\hline
\thead{Specific\\ Objectives}
    & \thead{Tasks}
        & \thead{Schedule}
            & \thead{Milestones}                        \\
    \midrule%\hline
1. Literature review and preliminary and background work
    & \vspace*{-1.2\baselineskip}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item[a)]   Literature review of theory and applications,
        \item[b)]   Analysing existing the problems,
        \item[c)]   Familiarizing with the various programs
      \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
      \end{itemize}
        & Half Term I
            & Prepare summary literature survey by end of term  \\
    \midrule%\hline
\end{tabular*}% \end{longtable}
    \end{table}
%            \end{scriptsize}
%        \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

- in `beamer` contents should be in `frame` enivironments.
- i would not centering cells content, left aligned looks better (to my taste. however, if you persist to have thewm centered, than line

  `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`

  replace width

  `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`

  and use `C{...}` instead of the `L{...}` in table columns options.
- use `longtable` in presentation has not big sense (or i miss something?
- `longtable` is by default centered, so `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` is superfluous.
- `longtable` had not to be in `table` environment.
- `scriptsize` is switch (from used font size to "script" size).
- for centering od column headers i use `\thead` from `makecell` package.

Comment: Very good. I like your work. Excellent. +1 Come on that we get to 100000 !! :-)